# NodeMCU RF522 connection not working

Tags: rfid, breadboard, nodemcu

I have a NodeMCU which is connected to a RF522 sensor and a LCD display.

I did the connection as follows

D4-SDA
D5-SCK
D7-MOSI
D6-MISO
GND-GND
RST-D3
3V-3.3V

LCD-I2C is connected nodeMCU as:
GND-GND
VCC-Vin
SDA-D2
SCL-D1

but for some reason when the RF522 doesn't work, the LCD works fine.
If I remove the RST connection of R522, the RF522 is working fine.

Why is my R522 not working if I connect the RST connection

Comment: crossposted at https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/89837/nodemcu-rf522-connection-not-working

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: what do you know about the RST pin?

Answer (score 0):

My RF522 sensor needed a strong pull up resistor of 1 kohm to VCC and a local 100 nF capacitor between VCC and GND for proper operation. It is possible, that other signals couple in if you use longer wires.

Also check the logic level of your output D3 and verify with the datasheet of the sensor (active high vs. active low).